# Is there an expression for $\exp\left(t z^{i}\partial_{z}^{j} \right) f(z) = $?

Tags: operator-theory, taylor-expansion

Does an expression for 
$$ 
\exp\left(t z^{i}\partial_{z}^{j} \right) f(z) = ?
$$ 
exist? For j=1 we have the usual expression for translation and scaling
$$
\exp\left( t \partial_z\right) f(z) = f(z+t)
$$ 
and
$$
\exp\left( t z \partial_z\right) f(z) = f(e^tz)
$$ 
Does similar expressions exist for higher order derivatives? How about if we restrict attention to $ f(z) = z^n $?